# Digital Ocean MysQL with high load average but no queries

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

My website is down because it cannot communicate with my MySQL database.

My database is inside the Digital Ocean server. My CPU, Load Average and memory is in the highest values right now:

[image]

[image]

Despite all that, since my website is down, I am not doing any queries, just not using the database. Here is a log from it:

[image]

[image]

Is it a problem from me? I am doing nothing at all with the database and I can't even connect with it since the load average is so high.

I sent digital ocean 1 ticket #06859716 explaining the situation. But they closed the ticket and said the problem was my queries.

It has been 4 days already, I reopened the ticket but they just ignored me. They don't have an online chat, just ticket support.

What should I do? For me, it looks like someone else is using my resources as a shared hosting.

Comment: What time is it?  When was the last backup done?  Were you logged in as MySQL's 'root' when you did `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?

Comment: Backups are done daily. Right now I can't log, it just doesn't let me. I can indeed ping the server, but logging right now is impossible, it just give me timeout.

Comment: smells like you got pwned. with that load average, you won't even be able to log into TTY. have you tried booting the VM with rescue mode?

Comment: Unfortunally, Digital Ocean doesn't give me access to Sudo or to restart MySQL

Comment: Can you share the URL to the site that has been down for days?  Have you asked Digital to stop / start MySQL?   Are you on a Shared or Dedicated plan at Digital Ocean?

Comment: Dedicated. My website is https://cardsrealm.com/en-us/ 
after yesterday they responded my ticket and everything end up ok now. I think they restart the MySQL. Load average is bellow 1 right now. I am reviewing everything now to be more efficient and thinking in hiring one second SQL just to read the primary one

Comment: No need to complicate your life with another instance at this time.

Comment: @Dinidiniz  I tried to Register on your site but did not get the email to confirm.  wlhauck@aol.com  Thank you

Comment: @Dinidiniz I am now registered on your site after receiving the confirming email.  Nice site.  Please drop an email to wlhauck@aol.com when you have a moment.  Thanks.